# Convergence in probability of a root of an equation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be iid Uniform $(0, 1)$ random variables, and set $\theta_n$ to be the root of the equation
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \theta^{X_k} = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2. 
$$
Apparently, this $\theta_n$ converges in probability to a constant. Is that easy to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we note that the equation
$$
\mathsf{E}\theta^X-\mathsf{E}X^2=0,\tag{1}\label{1}
$$
where $X\sim U[0,1]$, has the solution $\theta_0=\exp(-W(-3/e^3)-3)$ (here $W$ denotes the the Lambert W function). Replacing expectations on the LHS of Equation $\eqref{1}$ with sample averages yields its finite sample version:
$$
\Psi_n(\theta):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\theta^{X_i}-X_i^2\right).
$$
One may refer to $\hat{\theta}_n$ that solves $\Psi_n(\theta)\approx 0$ as an estimator of $\theta_0$. To show consistency (i.e. $\hat{\theta}_n\xrightarrow{p}\theta_0$) one needs to use the [ULLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Uniform_law_of_large_numbers). However, since $\theta\mapsto\Psi_n(\theta)$ is continuous and nondecreasing, we may resort to Lemma 5.10 in van der Vaart's ["Asymptotic Statistics"](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Asymptotic_Statistics.html?id=UEuQEM5RjWgC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image]